# A column is null in a table, yet another column in that table can be referenced to another table that contains the null column info - how?

Tags: sql, r, subquery, case

I'm new to SQL. I don't think what I'm trying to do is very difficult I just don't know the terminology well enough to search for it.

I have a table - table_1. It has a column - col_1. col_1 in table_1 is NULL. However there is another table, table_2, which is not NULL for col_1. table_1 and table_2 both contain a col_2, and with col_2 information we can derive col_1.

So essentially what I'm trying to do is this:

```
SELECT *
,CASE
WHEN table_1.[col_2] IS NOT NULL AND
    table_1[col_2] = table_2[col_2]
THEN table_2[col_1] ELSE NULL
END AS col_1
FROM table_1
```

In R, this would be written like this (assuming table_1 and table_2 are dataframes)

```
table_1 <- data.frame("col_1" = c(NA, NA, NA),
                  "col_2" = c("Red", "Green", "Blue"))

table_2 <- data.frame("col_1" = c("Red", "Green", "Red"),
                      "col_2" = c("Red", "Green", "Blue"))

table_1$col_1 <- ifelse(!is.na(table_1$col_2) & table_1$col_2 == table_2$col_2,
                        as.character(table_2$col_1), NA)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  table_1.*,
  COALESCE(table_1.col_1, table_2.col_1)   AS col_1
FROM
  table_1
LEFT JOIN
  table_2
    ON  table_1.col_2 = table_2.col_2
    AND table_1.col_1 IS NULL
```

The join conditions (predicate) only processes the join if there is a `NULL` in table_1's col_1.

The `LEFT JOIN` ensure no rows are discarded from `table_1`, even if there's nothing to join on to in `table_2`.

The `COALESCE()` takes the first "non-NULL" value from the arguments; so only reads `table_2.col_1` if `table_1.col_1` is NULL.

Comment: sure I did not think of the COALESCE at all. simple enough